# JQuery - dynamically adding a 3rd expand row to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I create a table by using DataTable in JQuery (on documentReady).

```
table = $('#transaction').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "servicingTransactionsLoad.do",
                "type": "GET",
                "dataSrc": function (json) {
                    for (var i = 0, ien = json.transactions.length; i < ien; i++) {
                        json.transactions[i].date = '<i class="icon-expand-handle color--secondary9 fa fa-plus"></i> ' + json.transactions[i].date;                            
                    }
                    return json.transactions;
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "date" },         
                { "data": "description" },
                { "data": "channel" },
                { "data": "amount" }
            ],
            "order": [
                [ 0, "desc" ]
            ]
        });
```

I have an event that fires when you click on the row to expand and give extra info:

```
    $('#transaction tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row( tr );

            if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
                // This row is already open - close it
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
                tr.find('.icon-expand-handle').removeClass('fa-minus');
                tr.find('.icon-expand-handle').addClass('fa-plus');
            }
            else {
                // Open this row
                row.child( createExpand2(row.data()) ).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');
                tr.find('.icon-expand-handle').removeClass('fa-plus');
                tr.find('.icon-expand-handle').addClass('fa-minus');
            }
});
```

createExpand2 is a method that builds a table that gets added as the child to give the extra info.

```
function createExpand2 (d) {
   // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td class="col-sm-3">Date Posted:'+
            '<br>' + d.datePosted+'</td>'+
            '<td class="col-sm-4">Merchant'+
            '<br>' + d.merchantName + '</td>'+
            '<td class="col-sm-3"></td>'+
            '<td class="col-sm-3">Miles Value'+
            '<br>'+ d.milesValue + '<br><a href="javascript:void(0);">Show calculation and detail</a></td>' +
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}
```

Now I need to expand the row to a third level if the href link is clicked. I basically want to call a method similar to expand2. It should have the same data passed into the method (as I will just use different parts of that object). I am not sure what the next step is. Currently I can see an error in the console if I click on the first child (I assume it is because of the event that fires if you click on any row of the table). So do I just modify expand2 with some kind of IF statement (to determine if we are on the main row or the child)? Or do I use a different event method (and what?) to catch when you click on the href link to open a third row and still having access to the "d" data object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you create your second level using jQuery methods instead of strings, you can easily attach click events to it and then use that to expand a third level

```
...
click_link = $('<a></a>').html('clickable link');
click_link.on('click', function(e){
  // function to show 3rd row
  createExpand3(table);
})
```

This link shows building rows dynamically that you can add click listeners to

https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/ysod0ghz/